# HttpClient.GetAsync() throws FileLoadException, can't find Newtonsoft.JsonNET

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm starting to use HttpClient.GetAsync() in a C# project. Whenever this method is called, it blows up, unable to find Newtonsoft.Json.

To get the method, I installed the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client nuget package, version 5.2.3. This lists a dependency on Newtonsoft.Json, v 6 or greater. Version 8.0.3 is installed.

What am I doing wrong? The nuget package should manage it's own dependencies? And why nuget for a system dll? The full error is as follows...

```
System.IO.FileLoadException was unhandled by user code
  FileName=Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed
  FusionLog=WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

  HResult=-2146234304
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
  Source=System.Net.Http.Formatting
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter..ctor()
       at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter..ctor()
       at System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatterCollection.CreateDefaultFormatters()
       at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.get_DefaultMediaTypeFormatterCollection()
       at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content)
       at Dimo.Notilus.Interfaces.Expense.HubHacienda.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<GetFromHub>b__0(Task`1 task) in C:\NotilusTNE\Sources\NotilusWeb\Agile\Dev\NotilusWeb\Dimo.Notilus.Interfaces\Expense\HubHacienda.cs:line 22
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Try this in Package Manager Console, Update-Package -reinstall -Project YourProjectName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add assembly binding redirect to your app/web.config

```
<configuration>
 <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
 </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I had a similar exception for System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource in asp net core. Adding the assemblybinding to /app.config solved it.